# Como simular ctrl+v

Tags: javascript

Existe alguma forma de simular um ctrl+v usando JavaScript?

Quero incluir um botão e um input. Ao clicar no botão, o que estiver na área de transferência deve aparecer no input.

O código é para uma página HTML que encurta links. Ela tem apenas dois campos: URL e nome do link.

Minha ideia é que o usuário copiar a URL e ao acessar a página, clique no botão pra colar o conteúdo no input.

Comment: Seria em uma página web ou esta desenvolvendo uma extensão para navegadores? Se for página web, gostaria de saber a motivação desta necessidade, me parece algo que pode ser resolvido de outra maneira, dependendo da necessidade.

Comment: Expliquei mais detalhes na pergunta

Comment: Não seria mais fácil enviar o link via GET ou POST para a outra página?

Comment: Caso ele venha de uma pagina do seu domino, enviar a *url* via requisição é uma boa ideia.

Comment: No caso, imagine que você está navegando aqui no SO e quer enviar o link pra alguém. Então você copia o link, vai até o site de encurtar URL e clica no botão para colar a mesma lá. Essa é a ideia. Portanto não pode ser via get

Comment: Eu disse via GET se o encurtador fosse uma ferramenta interna, se for um site qualquer na internet pode facilmente resolver usando as APIs fornecidas, assim como o twitter faz automaticamente quando você cola um link, no momento que você posta ele converte teu link para um link curto, basta seguir a mesma "receita".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vou responder porque não tenho acesso aos comentários. Depois posso editar essa resposta.

Copiar o conteúdo da área de transferência é algo muito bem protegido pelos browsers por questão de segurança. Simular a cópia de conteúdo da memória pode causar sérios problemas (imagine colar um número de cartão de crédito e enviar secretamente via ajax). Então, não, do jeito que foi descrito é impossível.

Contudo, pode ser possível simular um evento de "colar" via código. Talvez dê pra pensar em alguns workarounds dependendo de onde vem a informação. Você pode fornecer mais informações?

Comment: Agora você já consegue comentar! =D

Answer (score 2):

### Extensões usando WebExtension APIs

As extensões criadas usando WebExtension APIs podem interagir com a área de transferência do sistema usando document.execCommand(). Segue abaixo um exemplo que se encaixaria ao seu caso:

```js
function paste() {
  var pasteText = document.querySelector("#inputSaida");
  pasteText.focus();
  document.execCommand("Paste");
}
    
document.querySelector("#botaoColar").addEventListener("click", paste);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputSaida"></input>
<button id="botaoColar">Colar</button>
```

[Aqui tem a documentação completa da API.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard)

---

### Falta de suporte (ou permissão)...

Chrome não da suporte por padrão a isso, para funcionar você precisa dar acesso/permissão `clipboardRead` ao seu `manifest.js` e executar essa função em background, alguns links que podem ajudar:

- [Declare Permissions (Chrome Developers)](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions)
- [Pasting from the system clipboard using a Chrome extension (Github)](https://gist.github.com/srsudar/e9a41228f06f32f272a2)
- [Can't get execCommand('paste') to work in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969403/cant-get-execcommandpaste-to-work-in-chrome)
- [Why document.execCommand('paste') is not working in my extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503738/why-document-execcommandpaste-is-not-working-in-my-extension)

Comment: Só pra constar o AP não afirmou que se trata de um add-on.

Comment: Interessante, mas o sistema é bem simples, não sei se compensa mexer nessa questão de permissões. Detalhei mais a pergunta. Mesmo assim obrigado.

Comment: Entendi, a forma que conheço e sei que funciona é apenas com extensões, pois ai o usuário aceitaria você ter esse tipo de acesso ao navegador dele, de outra forma acho meio difícil de conseguir...

Answer (score 1):

Não vejo a necessidade de **tanto trabalho**, ainda mais algo que **implica a segurança do usuário**.

Se esta usando um encurtador de link próprio, você poderia simplesmente resolver com sessão ou `localStorage` ou `sessionStorage`, pode-se usar até mesmo um envio via HTTP usando `POST` ou `GET` do link gerado, desde que sejam todos no mesmo domínio ou você tenha "controle" sobre o tal "encurtador de links".

Se o encurtador de link for um serviço de terceiros (como [googl.gl](https://goo.gl) ou [bitly](https://bitly.com)) você poderia simplesmente usar uma API, geralmente os serviços de encurtar link possuem APIs para automatizar o serviço.

- Documentação do bitly: http://dev.bitly.com/api.html
- Documentação do googl.gl: https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started

Alguns exemplos:

### Encurtando link com googl

- c#: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/urlshortener/v1
- python: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/get_started
- Java: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/dev-guide
- php: https://github.com/sebi/googl-php
- ruby: https://github.com/zigotto/googl

Mais "clientes": https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/

### Encurtando link com bitly

- c#: http://code.google.com/p/bitly-dot-net
- php: http://github.com/Falicon/BitlyPHP
- php: https://github.com/hpatoio/bitly-api
- php: https://github.com/jsocol/bitly-api-php
- php: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/bitly-url-shortener (yii framework)
- python: http://github.com/bitly/bitly-api-python
- python: http://code.google.com/p/python-bitly
- ruby: http://github.com/nas/url_shortener
- ruby: http://github.com/playgood/get_shorty
- ruby: http://github.com/philnash/bitly (pode instalar usando `sudo gem install philnash-bitly`

Mais "clientes": http://dev.bitly.com/code_libraries.html

Comment: A necessidade é o pedido do cliente, mas vou dizer pra ele que não é viável

Comment: É uma imitação do googl

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo e esta imitação tem API? Se não tiver, existe algum motivo que lhe impeça de mudar para o bitly?

Comment: O site é icut.me é de um amigo e ele quer incluir essa funcionalidade. Dá uma olhada.

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo porque não usa o bitly até o seu amigo disponibilizar um sistema de integração (por REST ou outro tipo de webservice)?